# app indexing - how not to map all my website to the app

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I've been implementing google app indexing in my app, though it's turning out to be very hard for me to understand.
I've created the following intent-filter in my app

```
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <data android:scheme="android-app"
                android:host="com.towers.mywebsite" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I'd like to grab all the links like www.mywebsite.com?parameter=123 but NOT links like www.mywebsite.com/somethingelse

With the intent-filter above, my app is in the list of possible apps to open all the deep links like www.mywebsite.com...

My question is: am I doing it right? How am I supposed to filter the intent in order not to make all the links try and open tre app? I thought google would have chosen open-the-app-or-the-browser by checking which pages of my website do have the *link rel* attribute, but it seems like it only relies on my app intent-filter. Therefore, I need to tweak them in order to filter only the pages I want. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on markups if you don't declare App-Website association.
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app#declare-a-website-association

You can also try controlling indexing by creating noindex.xml file to specify the URLs you want excluded from the Google index.
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app#noIndex

Cheers,

MB